# Is necessary in Angular 2 put service in child module?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is necessary in Angular 2 put the service in child module or putting it in the provider of root module is enough?

Comment: depends on your requirement. if the service is **consumed globally** across modules, have it in your **RootModule** else **ChildModule** will suffice.

Comment: the service is consumed globally? is it  enough in root module?

Comment: I think below answer is clearly defining the service scope. :)

Comment: What is the diference between put the services in shared module and put the services in root module? Angular always inject the services in root module?

Comment: Well, I suppose in that case it wouldn't make a huge difference: the root `AppModule`-provided service "trumps" any instance provided at the shared level (unless lazily-loaded). So if you provided in both, you'll get the instance instantiated by `AppModule`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that everywhere in the app you should put it in root module otherwise only put it into child modules and if you need it for only one component then only put it in component providers. thats called singleton service. If service is added to root module then no need to add it to child modules or components.